# Regular expression to find a date substring Python 3.7

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a regular expression to find a specific substring within a string.

I'm looking for dates in the following format:

`"January 1, 2018"`

I have already done some research but have not been able to figure out how to make a regular expression for my specific case.

The current version of my regular expression is

```
re.search("[\w*?\s\d\d\s\d\d\d\d]", my_string)
```

I'm fairly inexperienced with regular expression but from reading the documentation this is what I could come up  with as far as matching the date format I'm working with.

Here is my thought process behind my regular expression:

`\w` should match to any unicode word character and `*` should repeat the previous match so these together should match some thing like this "January". `?` makes * not greedy so it won't try to match anything in the form of `January 20` as in it should stop at the first whitespace character.

`\s` should match white space.

`\d\d` and `\d\d\d\d` should match a two digit and four digit number respectively.

Here's a testable sample of my code:

```
import re
my_string = "January 01, 1990\n By SomeAuthor"
print(re.search("[\w*?\s\d\d\s\d\d\d\d]", my_string))
```

**EDIT:**

I have also tried :`[A-Za-z]\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2, 4}`

Comment: You're not matching for a comma at all ...

Comment: Oh I totally missed that, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `print(re.search(r'\w*\s\d{1,2},\s\d{2,4}', my_string).group()` it Works...carrefoul space in bracket accolades and comma to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern may be a bit greedy in certain areas like in the month name. Also, you're missing the optional comma. Finally, you can use the ignore case flag to simplify your pattern. Here is an example using re in verbose mode.

```
import re

text = "New years day was on January 1, 2018, and boy was it a good time!"
pattern = re.compile(r"""
    [a-z]+  # at least one+ ascii letters (ignore case is use)
    \s      # one space after
    \d\d?   # one or two digits
    ,?      # an oprtional comma
    \s      # one space after
    \d{4}   # four digits (year)
""",re.IGNORECASE|re.VERBOSE)

result = pattern.search(text).group()
print(result)
```

output

```
January 1, 2018
```

Comment: There's no need for the capturing parentheses; Python match objects already capture the matched text, so your code works as written without the parens (and omitting the parens avoids pointlessly capturing the match twice).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
In [992]: my_string = "January 01, 1990\n By SomeAuthor"
     ...: print(re.search("[A-Z][a-z]+\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}", my_string))
     ...:
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 16), match='January 01, 1990'>
```

1. `[A-Z]` is any uppercase letter
2. `[a-z]+` is 1 or more lowercase letters
3. `\s+` is 1 or more space characters
4. `\d{1,2}` is at least 1 and at most 2 digits

Comment: Use `\d\d?`, not `\d{2}` ... the day of the month might only be one digit, also `\w` isn't great for this problem (it will also match digits, its more likely we only want to match alphabeticals)

Comment: Also you might want to add optional space around the comma.

Comment: Mind `\w` also matches digits and underscores.

Comment: And you almost certainly want to use the word boundary marker, so you don't match `1234` out of a string `12345` or even `1234abcd`. And to do so safely, you want to use raw string literals (because otherwise `\b` means backspace, not word boundary), making it `r"\b\w+\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}\b"`

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
re.search("\w+\s+\d\d?\s*,\s*\d{4}",date_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
my_string = "January 01, 1990\n By SomeAuthor"
regex = re.compile('\w+\s+\d+, \d{4}')
result = regex.search(my_string)
```

result will contain the matched text and the character span.